# Can I std::forward the arguments in fold expression?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++17, fold-expression

In C++11 we have variadic templates, in which we can `std::forward` the arguments like in the following code

```
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

void printVariadic()
{}
template<typename T, typename... Args>
void printVariadic(T&& arg, Args&&... args)
{
   std::cout << arg << "\n";
   printVariadic(std::forward<Args>(args)...); // here we forward the arguments
}
```

But, in C++17 we have fold expression (and from my understanding it doesn't make recurive function call until last argument).

```
template<typename ... Args>
void print(Args ... args)
{
    ((cout << args << "\n"), ...); // did we here miss the part of `std::forward`?
}
```

In the online examples, I couldn't see a `std::forward` ing of the arguments, when fold expression has used.

Can I forward the arguments in fold expression? Or don't we need it at all?

It might a dumb beginner qestion, still I couldn't find an answer in online.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Can I forward the arguments in fold expression?

Yes

```
template<typename ... Args>
void print(Args && ... args)
{ // ...........^^
    ((cout << std::forward<Args>(args) << "\n"), ...);
}
```

The point isn't folding.

The point is how do you receive an argument.

If you receive it as value

```
void print(Args ... args) // <-- by value
```

you can't forward it (but you can move it)

If you want forward it, you have to receive it as forwarding reference, that is with a template type and a `&&`

```
template<typename ... Args>
void print(Args && ... args) // <-- forwarding reference
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I wasn't not aware about this. I will chekck as answers after a while(just to see wether anbody has to tell anything more about it).